# How to get current language in html.html.twig of theme

Tags: 8, theming

I need to get the current language in the html.html.twig file of my theme. In my page.html.twig I can use:

```
{% if (language.getId() == 'nl') %}
```

This does not work in my html.html.twig. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following snippet in your .theme file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['lang'] = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
}
```

Then, in your html.html.twig file use:

```
{% if (lang == 'en') %}
  // Your action
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 9 the answer is this:

```
{{ node.langcode.langcode }}
```